# Animated Film about "noise marines" in the 80s

Tags: story-identification, movie, psychic

I am looking to see if anyone can remember the title of an animated film about noise marine-like characters: their weapons were psychic guitars which they used to create a sonic/psychic attack.  I have looked for a good few years to find the title of this film however cannot find it, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I cannot add sound or noise-marine to the tags as I am still too young score-wise, if anyone fancies updating?:)

Comment: Don't worry about it. Tags are for when we expect a number of questions on a similar subject.

Comment: "noise marines" are in Warhammer 40k and use sound weapons.  I don't believe an animated film ever featured them, however, there was a band... http://www.last.fm/music/D-Rok

Comment: It was definitely a noisemarine-esque animated film, the only one of its kind I have seen.  I think it may have infringed on copyright nowadays as the characters were noise marines in all but name.

Comment: Are there no other details you can provide? Are you sure it was a feature-length animated movie? Can you pin down which half of the decade it was? What was the art style? As of right now, it only sounds like you're confusing Bluegrass & Melodia from SilverHawks with something else, or maybe that one episode of The Adventures of the Galaxy Rangers.

Comment: I truly wish I could remember more details, it was from the 80s or 90s however.  I will watch botht the shows you mentioned and post back if it was either:)

Comment: The band I think was called bolt thrower, had original 40k art on album cover.